# How to make chat box aligned at the bottom of the visible area of v-card

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I want to build a chat app with Vuejs 3 and Vuetify 3. However, I am having problem aligning chatbox with `v-card` component. The chatbox (green) is at the bottom of the **page** instead of at the bottom of the `v-card` component (the one with orange header).

[image: current status]

~~Here's the CodeSandbox link for reproduction: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/samzhangjy/observerx-web/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkjkbjis000h3u6qjgz7t7v2%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkjkbjir000c3u6qsqzuwo46%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkjkbjis000g3u6qk6nc7yxk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkjkbjir000e3u6qr9227649%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clkjkbjir000c3u6qsqzuwo46%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkjkbjir000b3u6qi92h0uan%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkjkbjir000c3u6qsqzuwo46%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clkjkbjir000b3u6qi92h0uan%2522%257D%252C%2522clkjkbjir000e3u6qr9227649%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkjkbjir000e3u6qr9227649%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clkjkbx5z00xo3u6qvqnegx0t%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkjkbx5z00xo3u6qvqnegx0t%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clkjkbjis000g3u6qk6nc7yxk%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkjkbjis000g3u6qk6nc7yxk%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clkjkbttm00mm3u6q7prnczot%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkjkbjis000f3u6q1q5os68p%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clkjkbjuu0019hgh62f6p8mjz%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkjkbttm00mm3u6q7prnczot%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)~~

**Update: there seems to be a problem with the CodeSandbox link. Use the GitHub link instead: https://github.com/samzhangjy/observerx-web**

I want it to be aligned inside the `v-card` and pin at the bottom even when scrolling (basicly putting it inside v-card). Also, I didn't find a way to make `v-toolbar` sticky (the orange header). Is there a builtin way to stick it to the top?

Thanks in advance!!

---

Code related to this if you don't want to use CodeSandbox:

- `MainContainer.vue`:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useTheme } from "vuetify";

const theme = useTheme();
const changeTheme = () =>
  (theme.global.name.value = theme.global.current.value.dark
    ? "light"
    : "dark");
</script>

<template>
  <v-container class="h-screen py-md-12 py-sm-5">
    <v-row justify="space-around" class="h-100">
      <v-card max-width="1000" height="100%" width="100%" class="overflow-auto">
        <v-toolbar color="tertiary-container" class="position-sticky">
          <template v-slot:prepend>
            <v-btn icon="$menu" color="on-tertiary-container"></v-btn>
          </template>

          <v-toolbar-title class="text-h6"> ObserverX </v-toolbar-title>

          <template v-slot:append>
            <v-btn
              icon="mdi-theme-light-dark"
              color="on-tertiary-container"
              @click="changeTheme"
            ></v-btn>
          </template>
        </v-toolbar>

        <v-card-text class="overflow-auto">
          <slot />
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<style scoped></style>
```

- `ChatPage.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <v-container class="h-100">
    <v-responsive class="align-center text-center h-100">
      <MainContainer class="container h-100">
        <div class="messages">
          <p class="text-body-1" v-for="i in 100">Line #{{ i }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="message-input-container">
          <v-textarea
            variant="solo"
            base-color="surface"
            bg-color="surface-variant"
            color="on-surface-variant"
            class="rounded-t-0 message-input"
            rows="3"
            no-resize
            rounded="0"
            v-model="currentMessage"
          >
            <template v-slot:append-inner>
              <v-btn
                icon="mdi-send"
                variant="tonal"
                size="small"
                color="primary"
                @click="sendMessage"
              ></v-btn>
            </template>
          </v-textarea>
        </div>
      </MainContainer>
    </v-responsive>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import MainContainer from "./MainContainer.vue";

const currentMessage = ref("");

const sendMessage = () => {
  console.log(currentMessage.value);
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
}

.messages {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.message-input {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  resize: none;
}

.message-input-container {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I get an error when opening the sandbox link, it says "Project not found", probably a permission issue

Comment: When you use `position: fixed;` it will be positioned fixed on the screen, you should try `position: absolute;`. on your `.message-input`

Comment: @MoritzRingler I've updated the post with GitHub link.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `position: fixed;` it will be positioned fixed on the screen, you should try `position: absolute;`.

So your final code should look like this:

```
.message-input {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  resize: none;
}
```

By the way you should fix the problem with the CodeBox link, I have not been able to access your project.

Comment: The chatbox now is pinned at the bottom of the whole container where I need to scroll to the bottom to see it... Not exactly what I wanted. btw I've updated the link to GitHub. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pinning toolbar and message input, you can have the messages list take up the remaining space between them. It is quite simple, just make the card a flex column and put the messages inside an overflow-auto container. However, for this to work, the card has to have a fixed height, as there is no remaining space if space is not limited).

```html
<v-card height="..." class="d-flex flex-column">
  <v-toolbar></v-toolbar>

  <div class="overflow-auto">
    <v-list :items="messages" dense></v-list>
  </div>
        
  <div class="message-input-container">...</div>
</v-card>
```

Have a look at the example in the snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    return {
      messages: ref(Array(50).fill(null).map((_,i) => `Message ${i}`))
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-card height="200px" class="ma-1 d-flex flex-column">
        <v-toolbar color="amber">
          <v-toolbar-title class="text-h6"> ObserverX </v-toolbar-title>
        </v-toolbar>

        <div class="overflow-auto">
          <v-list :items="messages" dense></v-list>
        </div>
        
        <div class="bg-green pa-3">Placeholder for Message Input</div>
      </v-card>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```